# MDX Query Error on SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

Function expects a tuple set expression for the first argument. A string or numeric expression was used.
I am designing the mdx query on my ssrs report.

Here is my MDX query:

```
SELECT 
     NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Order Quantity], [Measures].[Discount Amount], [Measures].[Freight], [Measures].[Extended Amount] } ON COLUMNS, 
     NON EMPTY { ([Customer].[Customer Key].[Customer Key].ALLMEMBERS * [Currency].[Currency Key].[Currency Key].ALLMEMBERS * [Currency].[Currency Name].[Currency Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Customer].[Gender].[Gender].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM (
      SELECT ( STRTOSET ( '{" & Join(Parameters!CurrencyCurrencyKey.Value,",") & "}') ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM [AWDW]
     )
```

Any Idea?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the call to `Join` does not return a correct expression. To make your query works, it should return something like the unique name of a `Currency Key`.

I do not know if you want to select 1 or several currency but the first argument of [StrToSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144782.aspx) must have a value like:

```
"{'unique name of the currency'}"
```

or

```
"{('unique name of the first currency') , ('unique name of the second currency')...}"
```

Comment: i need to pass multiple perameters to my mdx query. I thing i need to use join here......

Comment: Benoit is asking you to look at the parameter value for CurrencyCurrencyKey. Is it just the key value, or is it the Member_Unique_Name? It needs to be the Member_Unique_Name.

Comment: @user1602996 Can you give me a sample of unique name of your currency key?

Comment: @user1602996 You gave me the names of your currencies, I would like their ``unique names``...